# Does spring webflux supports javax bean validation?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have annotated my bean with some `@NotNull` and use the spring `@Valid` annotation in the `@GetMapping`. But this did not work.

The only difference I see from other applications is that I use `@EnableWebMvc` instead of `@EnableWebFlux`.

In the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/something")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> save(
                                @Valid @RequestBody MyBean mybean) {
        return myService.save(myBean)
                .map(RestResponses::ok)
                .defaultIfEmpty(RestResponses.empty());
    }
```

In the Application.java:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableWebFlux
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My bean class:

```
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed;

    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import java.util.Objects;

    @RedisHash("mybean")
    public class MyBean {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Indexed
        private String name;

        //getters, setters...

    }
```

and pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

...

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please add code of your get method?

Comment: @Orest, done! Thanks for your interest.

Comment: And `MyBean` class. Also what spring boot version do you have `2.0.0M1` ?

Comment: @Orest. Sorry, I've forgot.

Comment: So in dependencies you also have `org.glassfish:javax.el` correct?

Comment: Only as test...now that I saw my mistake. Thanks.
Your answer is right.
But my ExceptionHandler is not catching the MethodArgumentNotValidException as usual, because spring webflux is wrapping it in a WebExchangeBindException. But thats is another problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is some dependencies problem.
In the dependencies you can see those two libraries:

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
```

And according to documentation [Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#preface) you should provide additional dependency for [Unified Expression Language](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-uel)

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.1-b08'
```

After `@Valid` annotation should work as expected.

Comment: any chance on this issue ? I've the exact same problem when i remove the @EnableWebFlux all is fine